# How to wrap long word with TextRenderer DrawText in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, graphics, word-wrap, textrenderer

How can I draw a long word on a form **with word breaking** using TextRenderer DrawText() in vb.net? I thought it's a simple question and I tried all TextFormatFlags combinations but I can't find nothing solution. 
Can anyone help?
Here is a sample:

```
sText = "C:\Users\abiga\OneDrive\Works\AdreNDSzinkron\bin\Debug\AdreService.exe"
TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, sText, Font, New Rectangle(0, 0, Me.Width, Me.Height),
                      Me.Color,TextFormatFlags.<what is the correct flag?>)
```

I need this (nothing clipped):

```
C:\Users\abiga\OneDrive\Works\Adr
eNDSzinkron\bin\Debug\AdreService
.exe
```

Wrong solutions:

```
C:\Users\abiga\OneDrive\Works\Adr
C:\Users\abiga\OneDrive\Works\...
C:\Users\ab...bug\AdreService.exe
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First try `TextFormatFlags.WordBreak or TextFormatFlags.TextBoxControl` as your flags.

The docs say:

> WordBreak: Breaks the text at the end of a word
>
> TextBoxControl: Specifies the text should be formatted for display on a TextBox control

Combining these flags should give the expected result.

If that doesnt work then try using [`Graphics.DrawString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawstring?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Drawing_Graphics_DrawString_System_String_System_Drawing_Font_System_Drawing_Brush_System_Drawing_RectangleF_) instead:

`e.Graphics.DrawString(sText, Font, Me.Color, New RectangleF(0, 0, Me.Width, Me.Height))`

Comment: `TextFormatFlags.WordBreak or TextFormatFlags.TextBoxControl`

Comment: @Jimi - TexBoxControl was the key. Without it the WordBreak just wrapping at spaces but didn't "break" words. Thank you the solution!

Comment: I'll edit my answer accordingly, glad it's sorted :)

Answer (score 2):

Just to add some implementation details that can be used to evaluate the differences between [TextRenderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textrenderer)'s [DrawText()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.drawtext) method and the [Graphics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.painteventargs.graphics)'s [DrawString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawstring) method.

Clicking on the Form, the two methods show their differences in measuring and rendering the text.

```
Dim sText As String() = New String() {
    "C:\FirstLevelDir\FirstSubDir\AnotherDir\ADeepLevelDir\LostDeepDir\SomeFile.exe",
    "C:\FirstLevelDir\AnotherFirstSubDir\AnotherGreatDir\AwsomeDeepLevelDir\LostDeepDir\Some.exe",
    "C:\FirstLevelDir\SomeFirstSubDir\SomeOtherDir\AnotherDeepLevelDir\VeryLostDeepDir\FinalBuriedDir\SomeFile.exe"
}
```

In the Form's `Click()` event, draw `sText` lines, measuring their Width and Height using [TextRenderer.MeasureText()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.measuretext) and print them with [TextRenderer.DrawText()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.drawtext)

```
Private Sub Form1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Click
    Dim relPositionY As Integer = 0
    Dim lineSpacing As Single = 0.5
    Dim paragraphSpacing As Integer = CInt(Font.Height * lineSpacing)

    Dim flags As TextFormatFlags = TextFormatFlags.Top Or
                                   TextFormatFlags.WordBreak Or 
                                   TextFormatFlags.TextBoxControl

     Using g As Graphics = CreateGraphics()
         For x = 0 To sText.Length - 1
             Dim textSize As Size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(
                 g, sText(x), Font,
                 New Size(ClientSize.Width, ClientSize.Height), flags
             )

             TextRenderer.DrawText(g, sText(x), Font,
                 New Rectangle(0, relPositionY, textSize.Width, textSize.Height),
                 ForeColor, flags)
             relPositionY += textSize.Height + paragraphSpacing
         Next
     End Using
End Sub
```

In the Form's `Paint()` event, draw `sText` lines, measuring their Width and Height using [.Graphics.MeasureString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.measurestring) and print them with [.Graphics.DrawString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawstring)

> Note that the text boxed size in TextRenderer is relative to the
> Form.ClientSize, while in Graphics is relative to the Form's full
> Width.

```
Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Paint
    Dim relPositionY As Single = 0
    Dim lineSpacing As Single = 0.5
    Dim paragraphSpacing As Single = CSng(Font.Height) * lineSpacing

    Dim flags As StringFormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.LineLimit Or
                                     StringFormatFlags.FitBlackBox

    Using format As StringFormat = New StringFormat(flags)
        For x = 0 To sText.Length - 1
            Dim textSize As SizeF = e.Graphics.MeasureString(sText(x), Font,
                New SizeF(CSng(Width), CSng(Height)), format
            )
            e.Graphics.DrawString(sText(x), Font, Brushes.Black,
                New RectangleF(0, relPositionY, textSize.Width, textSize.Height))
            relPositionY += textSize.Height + paragraphSpacing
        Next
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow. Very detailed answer, didn't know about those differences.

Comment: @A Friend  Well, Graphics methods use the old GDI+ Apis, while TextRederer methods use the new-ish GDI Apis. When you use `e.Graphics` in the `OnPaint()` event, something may not work as expected, since projects are usually initialized with `Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(False)` (where "True" means "Use GDI+"), so Windows.Forms controls will use GDI and not GDI+ for rendering.

Comment: Oh I know that, I meant the bit in the blockquote, but thank you :)